# TCPDF don't display image with writeHTML

Tags: php, tcpdf

this question seems an evergreen on TCPDF...
I have an issue that's driving me crazy.

I have an html code that I use as "template" for my PDF, here I have my company logo.
Everything works fine on localhost (Windows), but when I move online, the image is not shown.
Pay attention: I don't get any error (ie the *Unable to get image* error) on my PDF the image is simple blank!
Infact if I click on the PDF on the position where the images it's supposed to be, I can select it, and Adobe enables the option "Copy image".

Obviously the image exists, is here, and permission are correct.
If I try to surf there, or view the generated HTML page, everything is fine.

This is the PHP code:

```
$pdf->SetMargins($params->get('pdfMarginLeft', 15), $params->get('pdfMarginTop', 27), $params->get('pdfMarginRight', 15));
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->lastPage();
```

Then this is my HTML code (I just skipped everything except the image):

```
<img alt="logo black" src="../images/logo_black.png" height="60" width="210" />
```

I've tried with the url (relative and absolute) and with the path (relative and absolute), the problem still occurs.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As things are working locally so you may try changing the image type from *png* to *jpg* and check after modifying your code accordingly and uploading the *jpg* on the server.

Comment: it can be a transparency issue..i am not sure..[here's a similar looking post](http://www.dolibarr.org/forum/527-bugs-on-a-stable-version/19407-tcpdf-error), which you may also go through where someone's suggesting a change in _tcpdf\_config.php_..check if that works for your _png_ logo..

Comment: i have an logo which is displayed multiple times in pdf
but it only appearing once then i converted to png file to jpg and its works like charm.Dont know the reason behind this but anyhow it is working

Answer (score 30):

This wasn't your problem, but it's a possible solution for people with a similar issue in the future. **Please make sure the HTML attributes have double quotes.**

```php
$html = "<img src='...' />"; // This will not work

$html = '<img src="..." />'; // This will work
```

Comment: +1, disregard Rishi Kalia's answer because both `PNG` and `JPEG` worked for me. It's the *outer* quotes for `src` the solved the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert image type "jpg/png" to base64.
 `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA...."/>` 
this may help you !

Comment: this doesn't work... but the <img src="@Base64bin" does

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I tried every solution above to no avail. It turned out I was missing width and height attributes. Adding those in, and using a root path ended up working for me:

`<img src="/images/image.png" width="50" height="50"/>`

Answer (score 1):

In my case IMG tag not working until I write full path to file

Not working

```
<img src="/pdfrender/XXX.jpg" width="50" height="50">
```

Working (localhost example)

```
<img src="http://site.local/pdfrender/XXX.jpg" width="50" height="50">
```

Comment: Please note that this way, your web statistics will contain `TCPDF` as user agent and it increases traffic on your server (you have to pay it twice, first the server's own request to itself + PDF output) which is you also don't want.

Answer (score 1):

It is also posible add image data inline as base64:

```
<img src="@Base64encodedImageFile" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a str_replace for the image src, and that works ok now.

```
$html = str_replace("../images", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/images', $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to 'resave' the images:

```
$image = 'images/logo_example.png';    
imagepng(imagecreatefrompng($image),$image);
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but as everybody is trying to add a "brick" here is a very strange detail I'm facing:

I have small "strips" of HTML that I put, one after other on a page.  If I put the first one, which has 2 png and a small text, on the file, the png are visibles on the PDF.
If I put the second one, which has 2 png and a small text, on the file, the png are visible on the PDF.
Now, if I put the two, ONLY the first one as the images. The second one as blank picture. If I change the picture of the second strip, images became visible.

*Detail: 1st and 2nd strips are using the same images!*

Notice this seems to happened **ONLY** with PNG image. So it seems there is a bug and you can't have two time the same PNG image on a page. Using JPG solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, locally it was working and on server blank image. I found out that htaccess password was the problem. I've put .htaccess file with the row `Satisfy any` to the folder with pictures and now it is working.