# img tag images not showing in server using html in TCPDF

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, tcpdf

I have the same issue described [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702891/tcpdf-dont-display-image-with-writehtml). But none of the solutions worked for me.

I integrated TCPDF with codeigniter

**The problem exists on my live server only, and the images are properly displaying on localhost. And I set the full permission too.**

Is there any working solution?

Answer (score -1):

To anyone who ends up at this question: The problem is most probably that the virtual host on the server is not set in the host file of the server. TCPDF tries to download the image it puts in the pdf.