# Tcpdf displaying image using url

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to generate PDF report. I want to print images on the PDF report but I have the URL for the images, example
https://myserver.com/media/4410/field.jpg

When I use this in Image() function of tcpdf. It does not show any image.
The images are not on the same server where I am running my php script to generate PDF reports.
How can I access these images and display them on the PDF. Why the URL is not working. Please suggest. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe you can insert the image using `$image = file_get_contents('http://example.com/image.jpg');`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59457767/5157032 This trick works for me

Answer (score 1):

You could store the image locally in your temp folder:

```
$image = @file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/image.jpg');

if ($image != '') {
    $filename = uniqid.'.jpg';
    file_put_contents('/tmp/'.$filename, $image);
}

// You can now insert your image using the $filename variable
$pdf->image('/tmp/'.$filename);
```