# TCPDF and insert an image base64 encoded

Tags: php, tcpdf

I've this string from Mysql db:

```
$img_base64_encoded = 

'data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'
```

It show "HI" in a image.
Now i want to embed this image encoded directly inside a PDF generated with TCPDF plugin but always get error:

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image:
```

And this is how to insert it:

```
$img = '<img src="' . $img_base64_encoded . '">';
$pdf->writeHTML($img, true, false, true, false, '');
```

I've also tried with:

```
  $pdf->Image('@' . $img_base64_encoded);
```

with the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use base64 stream in src rather first save the stream to a file then use it

```
$img_base64_encoded = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA0gA...';
$imageContent = file_get_contents($img_base64_encoded);
$path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'prefix');

file_put_contents ($path, $imageContent);

$img = '<img src="' . $path . '">';
$pdf->writeHTML($img, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Answer (score 45):

Well, you can actually, looking at the code you just neet to add a '@' before the base64 encoded string:

```
$img_base64_encoded = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA0gA...';

$img = '<img src="@' . preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $img_base64_encoded) . '">';

$pdf->writeHTML($img, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Tested with the last version of TCPDF

Comment: Been struggling for 5 days with this issue. A lot of conflicting info on how toget TCPDF to handle IMG tags for images exttacted from MYSQL but yours was the only solution that worked.

Comment: Thanks, really helped

Comment: Get a TCPDF error ( [Image] Unable to get the size of the image)....

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO! The trick is that preg_replace stuff. No idea what it does, but it works! :)

Comment: wow this is worked great, anyone know why i just need '@' + base64 string to show image ?

Comment: Does anyone know which way is supposed to work in TCPDF 6.2.3? I doesn't work for me whether I use the data:image or the @ approach. The PDF generates but no images are visible in the PDF. The same HTML string I use to build the PDF is returned to the browser and renders images correctly, they only do not appear in the PDF attached to a PHPMailer email using $pdf->Output('name.pdf', "S") and AddAttachmentString. The "E" parameter from TCPDF on the output method produces a corrupted pdf attached to the email.

Comment: For anyone who comes here and has the same issue as me (neither approach produces images in the PDF), make sure that your HTML properties are surrounded in double quotes, not single quotes in the HTML you pass to the writeHTML method.

Comment: Thank you dear @Gianluca It works like charm and you saved my life. I am using lumen 8.0 version and installed this package 'https://github.com/endroid/qr-code' and was facing this issue. It really helped me a lot. Thanks again :)

Comment: Getting this error - TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image:

Answer (score 5):

No need to write as HTML

```
    $img = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $img_base64_encoded));
    $this->tcpdf->Image("@".$img, 68, 208, 46, 46);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who generate an HTML variable for output, this is how I got it working:
Note that I am generating a barcode using the tc-lib-barcode library found [here](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode)

```
$img_base64_encoded = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($bobj->getPngData());
$text.= '<img src="@' . preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $img_base64_encoded) . '" width="200" height="30">';
```

Comment: You are adding 'data:image/png;base64' in the first line, and then stripping it out in the second.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. The only point to focus is the remove of "data:image/;base64," which is the beginning of my picture value in the database:

```
$img_base64_encoded = str_replace("data:image/;base64,", "", $logo);

// Image from data stream ('PHP rules')
$imgLogo = base64_decode($img_base64_encoded);

$this->setImageScale(7);
$this->Image('@'.$imgLogo);
```

Note: I use setImageScale to reduce the picture size

Answer (score 0):

Used this code with success for TCPDF to show image saved on mysql database. No need to save after reading from DB.
A little bit more polite, extracting imagetype from header data to provide it to Image API method.

```
            // check if there is a database image set
            if ($f_photo==""){
                $f_photoshow="/home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/images/default.png";
            }else{
                //define type (png/jpg) extracted from header - ex: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS.....
                $datasegments = explode(',',$f_photo);
                $extension    = explode('/', $datasegments[0]);
                $imagetype    = explode(';', $extension[1]);        
                $f_photoshow  = '@' . base64_decode($datasegments[1]);                  
            }   
            $mypositionY=$pdf->GetY()+7;
            $mypositionX=$pdf->GetX()+7;
            // Image([image], x, y, w, h, imagetype, link, align_after);
            $pdf->Image($f_photoshow,$mypositionX,$mypositionY,11,null,$imagetype[0],null,'N');
```