# Show base64 image using <img> tag in TCPDF?

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I want to show Base64 image in `<img>` tag. I have Base64 images in JSON array. I used Foreach to display image in my TCPDF table. but it shows nothing.
**JSON array example =>** `[{'SNO':0,'IMG': <encodeded-base64-code>}]`

I get image code from PHP, encode it into Base64 and used Foreach to display image in my TCPDF. but it shows nothing.

```
while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($prs))
{
    $result1['SNO'] = $row['SNO'];
    if (is_object($row['IMG'])) 
    {                   
       $img=$row["IMG"]->load();
       $row["IMG"]->free();
       $result1['IMG'] = base64_encode($img);
    }
    array_push($result, $result1);
    $res = json_encode($result);
}
    $dt = array();
    $dt = json_decode($res);
    $tbl = '<table><tr>
    <th>Sno</th>
    <th>Image</th></tr>';
    foreach($dt as $key => $lbl)    
    {
       $tbl .= '<tr><td>'.$lbl->SNO.'</td>';
       $tbl .= '<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$lbl-> IMG.'"></td></tr>';
    }
    $tbl .= '</table>';
    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
    $pdf->Output('create.pdf', 'I');
```

Display Base64 image in html table in loop.

Comment: I found an answer here: [TCPDF and insert an image base64 encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043581/tcpdf-and-insert-an-image-base64-encoded)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TCPDF and insert an image base64 encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043581/tcpdf-and-insert-an-image-base64-encoded)

Comment: i tried this code. But i have error -><strong>TCPDF ERROR: </strong>[Image] Unable to get the size of the image: C:\\Windows\\Temp\\preEC85.tmp