# TCPDF Embedded Base64 Encoded Images in HTML String

Tags: tcpdf

I have read several posts on this subject but didn't want to piggy-back on any of them with additional questions.

Specifically this post: [TCPDF and insert an image base64 encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043581/tcpdf-and-insert-an-image-base64-encoded)

I am generating a PDF from within a custom theme in Wordpress. I'm using TCPDF 6.2.3 (latest stable release, I believe).

I am building this PDF from the same HTML I am using to display on the page. If I embed the full base64 encoded string, it works correctly in the browser, but the image is missing from the PDF.

If I use the "@" method described in the linked post, I get a broken image in the browser (expectedly) but still nothing in the PDF.

All the rest of my HTML markup is rendering in the PDF, images are just not showing.

Is there some other setting or option I need to set in order to get the images to appear in the PDF, and/or can you spot anything I'm doing wrong here? No errors, the images are just not visible in the PDF.

This is how I set the image up:

```
        $imageLocation = $img_root.$imgsrc;
        $ext = end(explode(".", $imageLocation));
        $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imageLocation));

        //$response .= "<img src='data:image/$ext;base64,$image'>"; //works in browser but not in PDF
        $response .= "<img src='@$image' class='socf_image'>"; //does not work in browser or PDF
```

And here is the method to create the PDF:

```
function createPDF($response)
{
    // Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
    require_once('tcpdf_6_3_2/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('test');
    $pdf->SetTitle('test');
    $pdf->SetSubject('test');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('test');

    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
    $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    // set default font subsetting mode
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

    // Set font
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 14, '', true);

    // Add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    
    $html = $response;
    $pdf->writeHTML($response, true, false, true, false, '');
    
    return $pdf;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, fortunately, I was able to figure it out on my own. Perhaps this isn't the best forum for seeking help with this library? If anyone can suggest a better place to get help, I'd appreciate the direction.

Ultimately, the issue was two-fold:

1. The "@" notation is required for the PDf while the  approach is what works for displaying the HTML in browser. So a string replace before creating the PDF solves that.
2. This is the tricky part. The HTML needs to use double-quotes around the properties, not single quotes. My code was using double quotes for the PHP strings, so the HTML properties were surrounded with single quotes and that was the issue. Swapping the two quote types was the last piece of the puzzle to get the images to appear in the PDF.

Hopefully this will help someone else who is pulling their hair out trying to blindly find their way through this library like me.