# Image Not visible In TCPDF

Tags: php, image, pdf, tcpdf

here I have a Data i need it in Pdf But image not showing Below are my code
i already stored data in a variable

```
 $signature= $_POST['signature'];
```

> ```
> $tbl = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" border="1">
>      <tr>
>             <td style="width:25%;">Photo of the Documents '.$imagessignature.'</td>
>         <td style="width:25%">$photoofdoc</td>
>           <td style="width:25%">Approved By-'.$signature.'<br>$final_adminremark  </td>
>           <td style="width:25%;">
>          <img style="height:70; width:80px;" src="https://sbfasto.com/uploads/signature/'.$signature.'" />    
>          </td>
>     </tr>
>      </table>';
> $pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
> ```

Comment: Is your image base64-encoded? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043581/tcpdf-and-insert-an-image-base64-encoded/54520065#54520065

Comment: no but its visible if i put exect path, only problem with variable path.